# Meaning of "push-model" in context of RxJS/Immutable.js/AngularJS & likes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs, immutable.js

Please refer to the Angular 2.0 website: https://angular.io/

It talks about its great features. Specifically the following para:

===========================================

**Speed & Performance**

Achieve the maximum speed possible on the Web Platform today, and take it further, via Web Workers and server-side rendering.

Angular puts you in control over scalability. Meet huge data requirements by building data models on RxJS, Immutable.js or another push-model.

===============================================

What is the meaning of "another push-model"?? What is a "push-model"? Does it refer to "Models" as in Schema/Data-Model etc. Or something else?

I couldn't find it on the net.

Answer (score 4):

The way I understand it and would explain it:

While the web was built on a Request/Response "conceptual model" (think HTTP GET requests followed by HTTP 200 code Responses, etc) the new trend is to do less Requests, but more Responses: the "push model". Websockets are a perfect example: where you connect to an endpoint once and can stream back an infinitely long list of "real-time/live" updates. Reverse-Ajax / Long-Polling also come to mind as the old work-around to real-time updates (how facebook chat works for example).

Simply put: the server is "pushing" data to your browser.

This implies many things on the server side resources / server architecture too (the classic LAMP stack with PHP pre-fork workers for example is not fit for push model). Event-driven backends, process-connection sharing, etc, other key parts of the "push model".

Comment: it is bigger than server pushing data.  It is building everything reactive.  UI pushes work to webworkers.  Webworkers push data to UI to be viewed.  Servers push data to UI to be viewed.  UI pushes data to server for processing.  You can respond to things quicker if it gets pushed to you as soon as it is ready instead of having it sit there until some process polls for updates...

Comment: @Brandon your comment sent me through a bit of a head trip, I had never thought of it outside of the client/server sphere. Cheers --

Answer (score 2):

**push model:** Is a computer science term that refer to binding model into view like *mustache.js* and *handlebars.js*.

---

This means when the model changes it push this changes into the view.
You can find more about this pattern by searching for **data push** under Communication & Data flow models topics